# Combining various image channels after gaussian filtering produces white image

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library, python-imageio

I am trying to implement a gaussian filter for an image with dimensions (256, 320, 4).

I first generated a gaussian Kernel for the same and then individually perform the convolution on each of the 4 channel, i.e on all the 256*320 greyscale images. After performing this I wish to combine the image into a coloured image.

However, when I do this it does not seem to work as expected. The expectation is to see a blurred version of the original image with the blurring depending on the value of sigma. However, when I run the code, I simply get **a white image**, no blurring nothing.

```py
from PIL import Image
image = imageio.imread('graf_small.png')
print(image.shape)

def gaussian_filter(image, s):     
    
    probs = [np.exp(-z*z/(2*s*s))/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*s*s) for z in range(-3*s,3*s+1)] 
    kernel = np.outer(probs, probs) 
    channels = image.shape[2]
    final_output = np.ndarray((image.shape[0],image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    
    for i in range(4):
    
        channels = image.shape[2]
        im = np.ndarray((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]))
        print(channels)
        im[:,:] = image[:,:,i]
        #  generate a (2k+1)x(2k+1) gaussian kernel with mean=0 and sigma = s
        probs = [np.exp(-z*z/(2*s*s))/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*s*s) for z in range(-3*s,3*s+1)] 
        kernel = np.outer(probs, probs)
        # Cross Correlation
        # Gather Shapes of Kernel + Image + Padding
        xKernShape = kernel.shape[0]
        yKernShape = kernel.shape[1]
        xImgShape = im.shape[0]
        yImgShape = im.shape[1]


        strides= 1
        padding= 6

    # Shape of Output Convolution
        xOutput = int(((xImgShape - xKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
        yOutput = int(((yImgShape - yKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
        output = np.zeros((xOutput, yOutput))

        # Apply Equal Padding to All Sides
        if padding != 0:
            imagePadded = np.zeros((im.shape[0] + padding*2, im.shape[1] + padding*2))
            imagePadded[int(padding):int(-1 * padding), int(padding):int(-1 * padding)] = im
            #print(imagePadded)
        else:
            imagePadded = image

        # Iterate through image
        for y in range(image.shape[1]):
            # Exit Convolution
            if y > image.shape[1] - yKernShape:
                break
            # Only Convolve if y has gone down by the specified Strides
            if y % strides == 0:
                for x in range(image.shape[0]):
                    # Go to next row once kernel is out of bounds
                    if x > image.shape[0] - xKernShape:
                        break
                    try:
                        # Only Convolve if x has moved by the specified Strides
                        if x % strides == 0:
                            output[x, y] = (kernel * imagePadded[x: x + xKernShape, y: y + yKernShape]).sum()
                    except:
                        break
        final_output[:,:,i] = output[:,:]

final_output =np.dstack((final_output[:,:,0],final_output[:,:,1],final_output[:,:,2],final_output[:,:,3]))
        #print(merged.shape)
    return final_output
```

To test the function out, a helper function is called >

```
def plot_multiple(images, titles, colormap='gray', max_columns=np.inf, share_axes=True):
    """Plot multiple images as subplots on a grid."""
    assert len(images) == len(titles)
    n_images = len(images)
    n_cols = min(max_columns, n_images)
    n_rows = int(np.ceil(n_images / n_cols))
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(
        n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(n_cols * 4, n_rows * 4),
        squeeze=False, sharex=share_axes, sharey=share_axes)

    axes = axes.flat
    # Hide subplots without content
    for ax in axes[n_images:]:
        ax.axis('off')
        
    if not isinstance(colormap, (list,tuple)):
        colormaps = [colormap]*n_images
    else:
        colormaps = colormap

    for ax, image, title, cmap in zip(axes, images, titles, colormaps):
        ax.imshow(image, cmap=cmap)
        ax.set_title(title)
        
    fig.tight_layout()
```

```
image = imageio.imread('graf_small.png')
sigmas = [2]
blurred_images = [gaussian_filter(image, s) for s in sigmas]
titles = [f'sigma={s}' for s in sigmas]

plot_multiple(blurred_images, titles)
```

[image: OutputImage from code]

Comment: "doesn't work as expected". what did you expect? what did actually happen?

Comment: Hey! I have updated the description. TIA

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Some functions may need integer values in range `0..255`, other may need float values in range `0..1`, and if you use wrong values then they may reduce all values to `0` and you may get empty image.

Comment: you should use `range(channels):` instead of `range(4):` because images may have less channels (`RGB` with `A`) - but I'm not sure if you should change channel `A` with transparency.

Comment: code works for me with `RGB` image (without transparency channel) and it doesn't need `np.dstack()`

Comment: sometimes I see warning `"Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8"` when I save files and this can make problem. It may have problem to convert values. But I tested it only with [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) and it saves me correct image. maybe it makes problem when you display - I didn't try to display it with matplotlib but I saved in file and displayed with image viewers.

Comment: when I display it with matplot then I see warning `Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).` and I see white images. But in file it saves it correctly. So all your problem is with displaying it - you have to convert data from `float64` to `uint8` before displaying

Comment: Your images are in the range 0-255, but it's floating-point. Either cast to `uint8`, or divide by 255. Matplotlib wants floating-point RGB images to be in the range 0-1 (grayscale images will be scaled min to max, but for RGB images it doesn't want to do that, don't ask me why).

Comment: @furas: TYSM! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all problem is that you get images in `float64` but `matplot` needs `uint8` to display it.

`imageio` saves it in file as correct images but with warning `"Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8"`

Both problem can resolve converting to `uint8`

```
    return final_output.astype(np.uint8)
```

---

Full working code with few small changes

- I removed dstack
- I needed `size = output.shape[:2]` and `final_output[:size[0],:size[1],i] = output[:,:]`

```
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gaussian_filter(image, s):     
    
    probs = [np.exp(-z*z/(2*s*s))/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*s*s) for z in range(-3*s,3*s+1)] 
    kernel = np.outer(probs, probs) 

    channels = image.shape[2]
    print('channels:', channels)
    
    final_output = np.ndarray((image.shape[0],image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    
    for i in range(channels):
    
        im = image[:,:,i]
        
        #  generate a (2k+1)x(2k+1) gaussian kernel with mean=0 and sigma = s
        probs = [np.exp(-z*z/(2*s*s))/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*s*s) for z in range(-3*s,3*s+1)] 
        kernel = np.outer(probs, probs)
        # Cross Correlation
        # Gather Shapes of Kernel + Image + Padding
        xKernShape = kernel.shape[0]
        yKernShape = kernel.shape[1]
        xImgShape = im.shape[0]
        yImgShape = im.shape[1]

        strides= 1
        padding= 6

        # Shape of Output Convolution
        xOutput = int(((xImgShape - xKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
        yOutput = int(((yImgShape - yKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
        output = np.zeros((xOutput, yOutput))

        # Apply Equal Padding to All Sides
        if padding != 0:
            imagePadded = np.zeros((im.shape[0] + padding*2, im.shape[1] + padding*2))
            imagePadded[int(padding):int(-1 * padding), int(padding):int(-1 * padding)] = im
            #print(imagePadded)
        else:
            imagePadded = image

        # Iterate through image
        for y in range(image.shape[1]):
            # Exit Convolution
            if y > image.shape[1] - yKernShape:
                break
            # Only Convolve if y has gone down by the specified Strides
            if y % strides == 0:
                for x in range(image.shape[0]):
                    # Go to next row once kernel is out of bounds
                    if x > image.shape[0] - xKernShape:
                        break
                    try:
                        # Only Convolve if x has moved by the specified Strides
                        if x % strides == 0:
                            output[x, y] = (kernel * imagePadded[x: x + xKernShape, y: y + yKernShape]).sum()
                    except:
                        break
                    
        size = output.shape[:2]
        
        final_output[:size[0],:size[1],i] = output[:,:]

    return final_output.astype(np.uint8)


def plot_multiple(images, titles, colormap='gray', max_columns=np.inf, share_axes=True):
    """Plot multiple images as subplots on a grid."""
    assert len(images) == len(titles)
    n_images = len(images)
    n_cols = min(max_columns, n_images)
    n_rows = int(np.ceil(n_images / n_cols))
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(
        n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(n_cols * 4, n_rows * 4),
        squeeze=False, sharex=share_axes, sharey=share_axes)

    axes = axes.flat
    # Hide subplots without content
    for ax in axes[n_images:]:
        ax.axis('off')
        
    if not isinstance(colormap, (list,tuple)):
        colormaps = [colormap]*n_images
    else:
        colormaps = colormap

    for ax, image, title, cmap in zip(axes, images, titles, colormaps):
        ax.imshow(image, cmap=cmap)
        ax.set_title(title)
        
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# --- main --

image = imageio.imread('test/lenna.png')
print('shape:', image.shape)

sigmas = [2, 3, 5]
blurred_images = [gaussian_filter(image, s) for s in sigmas]
titles = [f'sigma={s}' for s in sigmas]

plot_multiple(blurred_images, titles)

for number, image in enumerate(blurred_images, 1):
    imageio.imsave(f'output-{number}.png', image)
```

Original image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: For clarification: Typically `float` images are `[0, 1]` and libs like scikit-image and matplotlib expect this. Numbers greater than `1` are treated as `1`, and `[1 1 1]` is a white pixel, hence the white image. Now, PNG doesn't support `float`, so ImageIO needs to convert to `int8` or `int16` when saving. `int8` has more support than `int16`, so we choose that, but it may not always be what you want, hence the warning.